# adjoint of forgetful functor related to localization

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Let $A$ be a ring and $S$ a multiplicative subset of $A$ such that
$1 \in S$. Let $G$ be the forgetful functor from $Mod_{S^{-1}A} \rightarrow Mod_A$.
Taking an $S^{-1}A$-module N and consider it as an $A$-module.
Let $F: Mod_A \rightarrow  Mod_{S^{-1}A} $ be its adjoint functor. 
It takes an $A$-module $M$ to $S^{-1}M$.

I want to show that $Hom_{S^{-1}A}(FM, N)$ is isomorphic to $Hom_A(M,GN)$
(my goal is to show that $F$ and $G$ are indeed adjoints). Could someone please
explain me how to show this isomorphism? Thanks!

Comment: I think you have $F$ and $G$ switched around in the homs.

Comment: I hope the problems are fixed now. Please let me know if I need more details. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a natural morphism $\alpha_M\colon M\to S^{-1}M$ (of $A$-modules) defined by $\alpha_M(x)=\frac{x}{1}$; given $f\in\operatorname{Hom}_{S^{-1}A}(S^{-1}M,N)$, consider $f\circ \alpha_M\colon M\to N$, which is a morphism of $A$-modules.

This gives a map 
$$
\operatorname{Hom}_{S^{-1}A}(FM,N)\to
\operatorname{Hom}_{A}(M,GN)
$$

Next, if $g\colon M\to GN=N$ is a morphism of $A$-modules, define
$$
\hat{g}\colon S^{-1}M\to N
$$
by
$$
\hat{g}\left(\frac{x}{s}\right)=\frac{g(x)}{s}\qquad (x\in M, s\in S)
$$
The only problem is proving that $\hat{g}$ is well defined. If $x/s=y/t$, then there exists $u\in S$ such that $u(tx-sy)=0$; then
$$
0=g(utx-usy)=u(t(g(x)-sg(y))
$$
which amounts to saying that
$$
\frac{g(x)}{s}=\frac{g(y)}{t}.
$$
Proving that $\hat{g}$ is a morphism of $S^{-1}A$-modules is easy. And it's easy also to see that $\hat{g}\circ\alpha_M=g$. Can you show that $\widehat{f\circ\alpha_M}=f$?

---

When you'll learn about tensor product, it will be easier.

Comment: Note: This (re)proves the univ. prop. of $S^{-1} M$.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Yes, of course.

Comment: @ergreg Thank you very much for this answer! Very helpful. Could you possibly tell me why it would be easier with tensor products?

Comment: @user170778 It's the standard Hom-tensor adjunction, as I mentioned in my answer to the other question of yours.

Comment: @egreg, don't we have to show the naturality of  this bijection?

Comment: @AguirreK Yes, but it's easy